# Sort array of objects by value in array of each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I am not sure if I wrote this question correctly, however.. I have this array of objects:

```
[
 {
   foo: 'Google',
   bar: 'Bing',
   pro: [
      'One',
      'Two',
      'Three'
   ]
 },
 {
   foo: 'Random string',
   bar: 'Something',
   pro: [
      'Five'
   ]
 },
 {
   foo: 'String',
   bar: 'Game',
   pro: [
      'Ten',
      'One'
   ]
 },

 // ...

]
```

And I need to sort it by the `pro` property where any of the array elements contains `text`. The umber of array elements is unknown, but at least 1.

**Where I am stuck with the logic:**

```
var text = 'On';

var results = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  // do another loop, than count and than check?
});
```

In this example, and after successful sort function, order of objects should become `0, 3, 2` or `3, 0, 3`, because `On` exists in two of them.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which should be the rule to select which one come first?

Comment: Does not matter. There is deeper logic behind that, but result is this, and i need to sort this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a short function to check if a value starts with the value of `text` and then use that as an input to `pro.some()` in your sort function, sorting `b` before `a` to sort in descending order.

```js
const arr = [{
    foo: 'Google',
    bar: 'Bing',
    pro: [
      'One',
      'Two',
      'Three'
    ]
  },
  {
    foo: 'Random string',
    bar: 'Something',
    pro: [
      'Five'
    ]
  },
  {
    foo: 'String',
    bar: 'Game',
    pro: [
      'Ten',
      'One'
    ]
  }
];
const text = 'On';
const hastext = v => v.indexOf(text) == 0;

arr.sort((a, b) =>
  b.pro.some(hastext) - a.pro.some(hastext)
);

console.log(arr);
```